# How can I create a new column from two columns excluding portions of it?

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics, tidyr

[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRsea.png)

Apologies for the really vague title but I want to know how I could create a new column from the two columns shown in the image, such that "NR" would be excluded from the new column.

For instance, the first row of the new column would be "no income" and the 7th row would be "Between 5001 and 10k". The "NR" will not be present in the new column.

I would really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: what should be the result in case both columns are 'NR'? and what if none of the two is 'NR'?

Comment: I have not thought about it actually. But, no two columns contain "NR" simultaneously in my case. The same answer to your second question, I have made sure we do not run into such scenarios. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In future it would be great if you provided example data using `dput` rather than a screenshot.

Assuming "NR" always appears in exactly one column, you could just do this to create a column called `new_col`:

```
df$new_col <- ifelse(df$new2 != "NR", df$new2, df$new10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would replace NR with empty strings and then paste all the columns together:

```
df %>% mutate(across(c(new2, new10), ~if_else(.x=="NR", "", .x))) %>%
   unite(Column, c(new2, new10), sep="")
```

Replace df with the name of your data.frame.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `coalesce` after changing the 'NR' to `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(across(c(new2, new10), na_if, "NR")) %>%
    transmute(new_col = coalesce(new2, new10))
```